# Abstract Class with enum Comparator: How to make it work?

Tags: java, enums, abstract-class, comparator

I would like to get the following thing to work.  My abstract class `T` extends `java.util.Comparator<T>` and should therefore allow me to use the `compareTo` method.  The problem is that `o1.t1.compareTo(o2.t1)` receives `The method compareTo(capture#2-of ?) is undefined for the type capture#1-of ?`

Could someone please explain the problem on a basic level and tell me how to potentially fix it?  Thanks a lot in advance.

```
public class TypeTypeComparator<T extends java.util.Comparator<T>> {

    public T t1;
    public T t2;

    public TypeTypeComparator() {
        this.t1 = null;
        this.t2 = null;
    }

    public TypeTypeComparator(T t1, T t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    public static enum Comparator implements java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<?>> {
        T1_SORT {
            public int compare(TypeTypeComparator<?> o1, TypeTypeComparator<?> o2) {
                return o1.t1.compareTo(o2.t1);
            }},
        T2_SORT {
            public int compare(TypeTypeComparator<?> o1, TypeTypeComparator<?> o2) {
                return o1.t2.compareTo(o2.t2);
            }};

        public static java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<?>> getComparator(final Comparator... options) {
            return new java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<?>>() {
                public int compare(TypeTypeComparator<?> o1, TypeTypeComparator<?> o2) {
                    for ( Comparator option : options ) {
                        int result = option.compare(o1, o2);
                        if ( result != 0 )
                            return result;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were few issues in your implementation, I have solved the issues for you :)

> **1st issue**
>   `public class TypeTypeComparator<T extends`**`java.util.Comparator`**`<T>> {`

You need `Comparable` here instead of a `Comparator` here. So it becomes
`public class TypeTypeComparator<T extends`**`Comparable`**`<T>> {`

> **2nd issue**
>   Recursive generics in Comparable forces you to use **`?`** for generics
>   `public static enum Comparator implements`**`java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<?>>`**
>   or
>   `public static enum Comparator implements java.util.Comparator<`**`TypeTypeComparator<Comparable<?>>`**`>`

You will again need to put **`?`** due to recursive generic declaration in Comparable, so instead I recommend you resolve the recursive generics of `Comparable` as follows:

```
interface Comp extends java.lang.Comparable<Comp> {}
```

Now you need to replace all **`?`** with **`Comp`** and you are done.

---

Here is the complete implementation:

```
interface Comp extends Comparable<Comp> {}

public class TypeTypeComparator<T extends Comp> {

    public T t1;
    public T t2;

    public TypeTypeComparator() {
        this.t1 = null;
        this.t2 = null;
    }

    public TypeTypeComparator(T t1, T t2) {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    public static enum Comparator implements java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<Comp>> {
        T1_SORT {
            @Override
            public int compare(TypeTypeComparator<Comp> o1,
                    TypeTypeComparator<Comp> o2) {
                return o1.t1.compareTo(o2.t1);
            }
        },
        T2_SORT {
            @Override
            public int compare(TypeTypeComparator<Comp> o1,
                    TypeTypeComparator<Comp> o2) {
                return o1.t2.compareTo(o2.t2);
            }
        };

        public static java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<Comp>> getComparator(final Comparator... options) {
            return new java.util.Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<Comp>>() {
                public int compare(TypeTypeComparator<Comp> o1, TypeTypeComparator<Comp> o2) {
                    for ( Comparator option : options ) {
                        int result = option.compare(o1, o2);
                        if ( result != 0 )
                            return result;
                    }
                    return 0;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch;  this does in fact solve it. :)   Also, I would have definitely not come up with the interface coding ... always awesome to see something new (to me).

Answer (score 1):

I would replace `Comparator<TypeTypeComparator<?>>` with `Comparator<TypeTypeComparator>`  The problem is that one `<?>` and another are not equivalent.

BTW It appear you really want to be using Java 8 which would make all of this trivial.  Java 7 will be End Of Life'd in April.

---

In Java 8 you would need a class like you have i.e. all the code would disappear.  You can use built in functions like

```
list.sort(comparing(Type::getField1)
         .andThen(comparing(t -> getItem().getOtherField())
         .andThen(comparing(Type::getField2).reversed()));
```

Comment: I tried stripping all the `<?>`, but that didn't change the error.  @Java 8:  I am actually using J8.  Just out of curiosity:  How would the implementation in J8 differ to J7?

Comment: @dotwin You will be better off reading the Java 8 Release Notes. In fact, every developer should be keeping up with changes; even in minor releases. It makes it easier to roll with the punches when is time to upgrade.

Comment: This will probably not fix all your problems, but the `T` in `TypeTypeComparator` should probably extend `Comparable`. That's where you would get the `compareTo` method from.

Comment: @hfontanez: your advice is so generic its not even helpful. At least list the features that could simplify the above code.

Comment: @dotwin the construction of comparisons is very different, see my answer

Comment: @jepio why do you feel you must speak for the OP. There are only so many characters you can type here.  Instead of wasting your time by telling me how my advice is generic, why didn't you do what you are telling me I should have done?